# Why Cocos2D iPhone v1.x Slow in iPhone 5S?

Tags: ios6, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone, ios7, iphone-5

We have an app that is using `Cocos2D v1.x` and we can't update it to the latest version. When loading on `iPhone 5S`, which I believe it should load faster but it seems not. Let's say it takes 7 seconds to load a scene in other devices which most likely running on `iOS6` and when we load it on `iPhone 5S` it takes around 11 seconds.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: How are you measuring ? how can you assert that cocos2d is related to the slowness ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I used `Time Profiler` and the draw scene from `Cocos2D` was much longer in `iPhone 5S`, and also in `iOS7` devices.

Comment: OK, now that you have a profile, what are the bottlenecks? These methods should be obvious at the top of your time profile and should point to what is taking the most time during the loading of your scene.

Comment: be careful with drawScene : the 'update' method of all scene descendants is accounted for in there. This is where you are probably doing most of YOUR own logic. It could be something in there that takes a performance hit on the 5S.

Comment: Thanks! I found out that there's a call that was accessing a file but not needed anymore. I removed that call and the issue was fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks! I found out that there's a call that was accessing a file but not needed anymore. I removed that call and the issue was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Cocos2d 1.x use OpenGL 1, and Cocos2d 2.x use OpenGL 2. Moreover, iPhone 5S use OpenGL 3.

Xcode 5 will not support OpenGL 1 correctly and will use some deprecated functions.

So, the game that was already compiled and published will run normally. But if you compile this game using iOS SDK 7.0, you will run with some conflicts.

You have two options: Update cocos2d, or use an old Xcode version with old iOS SDK

Comment: As far as Xcode support, I don't believe this is correct. I have a project here that has both OpenGL ES 1.1 and 2.0 rendering paths, and Xcode 5 has no problems at all with the 1.1 side of things. As Apple states, the 1.1 functions effectively map the fixed function pipeline onto the programmable 2.0-compatible hardware. Support for OpenGL ES 3.0 doesn't really change that.